# How to make this clean?

Tags: wp-editor

I test on localhost

```
$MySITE = 'http://www.ciusan.com';

wp_editor($MySITE, 'CNB_Content', $settings = array('media_buttons' => false,) );
```

but on output always:

```
http://localhost/\"http://www.ciusan.com\"
```

How to become only:

```
http://www.ciusan.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$MySITE = 'This is my site: <a href="' . esc_url('http://www.ciusan.com') . '">Ciusan</a>';

wp_editor($MySITE, 'CNB_Content', $settings = array('media_buttons' => false,) );
```

Comment: How about

`$MySITE = 'This my site: <a href="http://www.ciusan.com">Ciusan</a>`';

Comment: @DannieHerdyawan updated.

Comment: @DannieHerdyawan sorry, added the link now, did this work for you?

Comment: sorry still same...

Comment: @DannieHerdyawan just tested this on a fresh install, it's working fine for me.  Perhaps you have another plugin or function that is interfering.

Comment: I just install new WP version 4 with testing 1 plugin because i want create a plugin. This the plugin: http://www.ciusan.com/test-plugin.zip